# While-loop not exiting in python

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to teach myself python right now, and I'm using exercises from "Learn Python The Hard Way" to do so.

Right now, I'm working on an exercise involving while loops, where I take a working while loop from a script, convert it to a function, and then call the function in another script.  The only purpose of the final program is to add items to a list and then print the list as it goes.

My issue is that once I call the function, the embedded loop decides to continue infinitely.

I've analyzed my code (see below) a number of times, and can't find anything overtly wrong.

```
def append_numbers(counter):
    i = 0
    numbers = []

    while i < counter:
        print "At the top i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i += 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

count = raw_input("Enter number of cycles: ")

print count
raw_input()

append_numbers(count)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe you want this.

```
count = int(raw_input("Enter number of cycles: "))
```

Without converting the input to integer, you end up with a string in the `count` variable, i.e. if you enter `1` when the program asks for input, what goes into count is `'1'`.

A comparison between string and integer turns out to be `False`. So the condition in `while i < counter:` is always `False` because `i` is an integer while `counter` is a string in your program.

In your program, you could have debugged this yourself if you had used `print repr(count)` instead to check what the value in `count` variable is. For your program, it would show `'1'` when you enter 1. With the fix I have suggested, it would show just `1`.

Answer (score 1):

convert the input string to integer... `count=int(count)`

Answer (score -1):

Above has been cleared why  the while looped for ever. It loops for a lot(=ASCII code which is really big)

But to fix the while you can  simply:

```
while i<int(counter):
    print "At the top i is %d" % i
    numbers.append(i)
```

Answer (score -4):

`raw_input` returns a string, but `i` is an integer.  Try using `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: `input` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`. and eval is evil.. don't do that.

Comment: This is only true in Python 3, where they got rid of the `raw_input` keyword.

Comment: This is nonsense - eval is awkward, but it is not evil.  There is no security risk here.

Comment: Are you kidding?! There's absolutely a security risk here. It's totally possible to produce a string that, when eval'd, downloads and runs a trojan.

Comment: @comex It isn't nonsense. Using `eval()` in a program is a HUGE security risk. One of the most basic principles of computer security is, "All input is evil,  unless proven otherwise." You show no respect to this principle when you use `eval()` and the disrespect to this principle is only magnified when you use `eval()` with `raw_input()` because now you not only accept an input that could be evil but you also execute and evaluate it.

Comment: There is no security risk because except in some crazy implementation where this script is directly connected to the network, the user is running the script himself and may as well execute his "evil" command more directly.  Don't blindly adhere to principles.

Comment: @comex It is a security risk even in common implementations with setuid bit set. Do not blindly assume that the user is running the script himself. The script need not be connected to the network. A program with a setuid bit set can also lead to privilege escalation even if a user with lower priveleges is executing the script. He can then enter any valid Python statement to the `raw_input` and get it executed by this script with higher privelege if he has to follow your solution. In other words, you have provided a terrible solution that any security conscious programmer knows why to avoid.